# Hibernate Critieria join two tables with condition on 2nd table and result the 1st table

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I have a question using Hibernate Criteria, I need to convert this query using criteria.

SELECT * FROM A a_ INNER JOIN B b_ ON a_.column1=b_.column1 AND b_.column2 IN (X,Y) AND active='Y';

I need the result as table A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the associations are defined, see http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-associations

In case associations are not specified in the entities definition, you can't use criteria.
You can use HQL to do inner joins (need to write in [implicit join notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Inner_join)), for doing left joins you have to use native SQL.

Answer (score 2):

I just solved this issue, here is my code

```
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(ProductOffer.class);
        criteria.setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);

        Date effDate = TypeConvertUtil.toDate(param.get("effDate"));

        criteria.add(Restrictions.le("effDate", effDate));
        criteria.add(Restrictions.gt("expDate", effDate));


        criteria.createAlias("productOfferPropDefs", "def",JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN);
        criteria.setFetchMode("productOfferPropDefs", FetchMode.JOIN);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.le("def.effDate", effDate));
        criteria.add(Restrictions.gt("def.expDate", effDate));


        criteria.createAlias("def.productOfferProps", "prop",JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN);
        criteria.setFetchMode("def.productOfferProps", FetchMode.JOIN);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.le("prop.effDate", effDate));
        criteria.add(Restrictions.gt("prop.expDate", effDate));

        productOfferList = criteria.list();
```

Please beware that

```
criteria.createAlias("productOfferPropDefs", "def",JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN);
```

this parameter is important:

```
JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN
```

if you did not use it, and your relation is one-to-many, it will hit the 1:N classic issue for hibernate

Comment: could you please write here also resulting sql query? Tables and column names does not match with example in question.